# CharacterController Collider Script issue

Tags: collider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJOSb.jpg)

This script is supposed to End the game if Player hits something infront(z axis). But instead, the Player dies even if it hits anything in x and even y axis(which is ground) so game ends the moment my player touches the ground. Requesting help. I'm new to Unity and c#. So please don't abuse me if the solution is too obvious.

Comment: Hi there, could you please add all your code to the question, rather than linking an image.

Answer (score 0):

I think the player dies immediately because the ground also have a collider which the player touches. try to add a tag to the object in front the player, and in your code check the tag before calling the end game function.

```
if(hit.gameobject.tag == "tag" && hit.point.z > transform.position.z + controller.radius)
Death();
```